# SwiftLint: Exclude file for specific rule

Tags: swiftlint

I'm trying to do something like this in my .swiftlint.yml file:

```
force_cast:
  severity: warning # explicitly
  excluded:
    - Dog.swift
```

I have this code and I don't like the force_try warning I'm getting for it:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Constants.dogViewCellReuseIdentifier,
                                                               forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DogViewCell
```

I want to suppress the warning for this file by excluding this file from the rule.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 114):

Well, if you don't want some specific rules to be applied to a specific file you can use the technique mentioned by @Benno Kress. For that you need to add a comment in your swift file as given below.

The rules will be disabled until the end of the file or until the linter sees a matching enable comment:

```
// swiftlint:disable <rule1> 

   YOUR CODE WHERE NO rule1 is applied

// swiftlint:enable <rule1>
```

It is also possible to skip some files by configuring swiftlint. 
add a "**.swiftlint.yml**" file in the directory where you'll run SwiftLint.

Add the following content to exclude some files. Lets say file1, file2 ... etc

```
excluded: 
  - file1
  - file2
  - folder1
  - folder1/ExcludedFile.swift
```

To disable some rules completely add the following to the same "**.swiftlint.yml**" file.

```
disabled_rules: # rule identifiers to exclude from running
  - colon
  - comma
  - control_statement
```

for more information, refer the following links.

https://swifting.io/blog/2016/03/29/11-swiftlint/

https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#disable-rules-in-code

Answer (score 27):

You can write `// swiftlint:disable force_cast` at the beginning of the file in which you want to supress the warning for this rule. It gets disabled until the end of the file or until you add the line `// swiftlint:enable force_cast`.

Source: https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#disable-rules-in-code

Comment: Update for inline // swiftlint:disable:this force_cast

Answer (score 15):

I just get rid with  **force_cast**

**Step 1:**

```
cd path-to-your-project
```

**Step 2:**

```
touch .swiftlint.yml
```

**Step 3:**
`open  .swiftlint.yml` and add the rule

```
disabled_rules: # rule identifiers to exclude from running
 - force_cast
```

[image]

Reference - https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#disable-rules-in-code

Comment: How to open .swiftlint.yml ?

Comment: @RajeshKumarR you can open it using Subline text editor.

Comment: it's a hidden file, so run `open .swiftlint.yml`

Comment: @Andrew yes. Or if finder has show hidden file settings then Direct double click will also work.

Answer (score 4):

Configure SwiftLint by adding a .swiftlint.yml file from the directory you'll run SwiftLint from. Here is the complete set of options you can use in your `.swiftlint.yml` file

```
disabled_rules: # rule identifiers to exclude from running
  - colon
  - comma
  - control_statement
opt_in_rules: # some rules are only opt-in
  - empty_count
  # Find all the available rules by running:
  # swiftlint rules
included: # paths to include during linting. `--path` is ignored if present.
  - Source
excluded: # paths to ignore during linting. Takes precedence over `included`.
  - Carthage
  - Pods
  - Source/ExcludedFolder
  - Source/ExcludedFile.swift
  - Source/*/ExcludedFile.swift # Exclude files with a wildcard
analyzer_rules: # Rules run by `swiftlint analyze` (experimental)
  - explicit_self

# configurable rules can be customized from this configuration file
# binary rules can set their severity level
force_cast: warning # implicitly
force_try:
  severity: warning # explicitly
# rules that have both warning and error levels, can set just the warning level
# implicitly
line_length: 110
# they can set both implicitly with an array
type_body_length:
  - 300 # warning
  - 400 # error
# or they can set both explicitly
file_length:
  warning: 500
  error: 1200
# naming rules can set warnings/errors for min_length and max_length
# additionally they can set excluded names
type_name:
  min_length: 4 # only warning
  max_length: # warning and error
    warning: 40
    error: 50
  excluded: iPhone # excluded via string
identifier_name:
  min_length: # only min_length
    error: 4 # only error
  excluded: # excluded via string array
    - id
    - URL
    - GlobalAPIKey
reporter: "xcode" # reporter type (xcode, json, csv, checkstyle, junit, html, emoji, sonarqube, markdown)
```

Reference: github.com/realm/SwiftLint#disable-rules-in-code

Comment: you are just saying what this article does 
https://realm.github.io/SwiftLint/

Answer (score 1):

**Configure Excluded Files/Folders:**

In the .swiftlint.yml file, you can use the excluded parameter to specify the files or folders that you want to exclude from SwiftLint linting. Here's an example of how to exclude specific files and folders:

yaml

```
excluded:
  - Carthage
  - Pods
  - SomeFolder/ExcludedFile.swift
  - AnotherFolder/ExcludedFolder/**
```

**Configure Excluded Files/Folders For specific Rule:**

> Start of file you can disable any particular rule

```
// swiftlint:disable type_name (Rule)
```

> End of the file you can enable the swift lint

```
// swiftlint:enable type_name (Rule)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new `.swiftlint.yml` file to the excluded folder and override rules there:
`project_root/.swiftlint.yml`:

```
opt_in_rules:
  force_unwrapping
.. and other rules
```

and in

`project_root/your_excluded_folder/.swiftlint.yml`

```
disabled_rules:
  - force_unwrapping
```

Then  `force_unwrapping` will not be applied to `your_excluded_folder` and all subfolders

Config file from subfolder will "override" rules in the root config file.

This is useful for example for the unit tests folder

Comment: Note that if you go this route (nested configurations), you can't use the `--config` parameter when invoking `swiftlint`. See [this](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#nested-configurations) part of the readme for more info.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is a better approach:

```
guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Constants.dogViewCellReuseIdentifier,
                                                               forIndexPath: indexPath) as? DogViewCell else {
return UITableviewCell()
}
```