# SwiftLint -Disable Line Length Rules in a specific file

Tags: ios, swift, swiftlint

Current SwiftLint rules:

```
file_length:
  warning: 800
  error: 1500
```

The error

[image]

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41378617/4833705) but the error doesn't go away

```
// swiftlint:disable force_cast

import UIKit

class MyClass: UIViewController {

}

// swiftlint:enable force_cast
```

**How can I ignore SwiftLint rules in certain file?**

Comment: huh, 800 is a pretty big number for just a warning limit.

Comment: I inherited the project from someone else. I thought it was too low. What do you think the warning limit should be?

Comment: Personally, my limits are `function_body_length: 40`, `file_length: 500` (error limits). I saw people using even less but in my opinion using lower limits, especially for functions, destroys readability. A file limit shouldn't be definitely greater than 1000 lines. A file with 1000 lines is just too much. Refactor your code out, use view components, child view controllers, move your business code to services etc. Your controllers should be relatively simple classes.

Comment: 500 is very low!!! Abstracting code is a skill in and of itself. I’ll try it though. Thanks for the advice 

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The rule name is `file_length`, so you have to disable this rule:

```
// swiftlint:disable file_length

import UIKit

class MyClass: UIViewController {

}
```

Note: `// swiftlint:enable <rule>` is for cases when you want to ignore a specific rule only in a small code block (like a single func). If you'd like to disable a rule in file scope, there is no need to enable anything.

See [Swiftlint docs](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#disable-rules-in-code).

Comment: For me, it is `line_length`.

Comment: @ChuckZHB that's a different rule